# Get Age of Active Directory Domain

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2012

What is a method to determine the age of an Active Directory domain? We have taken over a customer with a poorly-configured Active Directory domain, and they need to determine when the domain was configured (this was likely done several server versions ago, possibly 15 years ago, and therefore we can't look at the date the OS was installed).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In AD Users and Computers:

Select View > Advanced

Right-click on the domain > properties.

Object tab, the Created date.